# Cannot connect JBL Flip 6 with Audio repeater

Tags: audio, repeater

I have tried to connect two of my JBL Flip 6 devices simultaneously via Audio Repeater, but it does not connect. I have tried connecting by changing the options several times but still it does not work.
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first two attempts, you tried to use sampling rate 48000 while JBL only supports 44100. The error message explains this, error "there is no match..." means that the driver didn't find the requested format in its list of supported formats.

In third attempt, the requested format is supported, but the driver was unable to create a pin instance for some reason ("a device is not functioning"). For example, it might occur if some application(s) and/or system service(s) use the endpoint associated with this pin. Try to close all audio-related applications before clicking Start.